# Is there a more elegant way to catch multiple date parsing formats in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working on learning to clean datasets and am encountering multiple date formats. There appears to be only two formats datetimes were stored as. The below code works fine, but feels clunky. Is there a better (or faster) way to handle multiple formats in a DataFrame? If it were only one format, it would be doable in just one line and I like avoiding try/except statements if I can.

For reference, the data goes from 1963 to 2010, so declaring the date_parsed column as 2023 seemed safe to me. Thanks!

```
data['date_parsed'] = pd.to_datetime('01/01/2023', format='%m/%d/%Y')

for i in range(len(data.Date)):

try:
    data['date_parsed'][i] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date[i], format='%m/%d/%Y')

except:
    data['date_parsed'][i] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date[i], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Comment: what do you mean by "*way to handle multiple formats*"? do you want to exclude certain formats, or only parse specific ones?

Comment: see also [Handling multiple datetime formats with pd.to_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47256212/10197418) or [parse multiple date format pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62211539/10197418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values from non matched values in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) by parameter `errors='coerce'`:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', errors='coerce')

data['date_parsed'] = d1.fillna(d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with a list comprehension of [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and your various formats, to handle any number of formats:

```
from functools import reduce

formats = ['%m/%d/%Y', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ']

data['date_parsed'] = reduce(lambda a,b: a.fillna(b),
                             [pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],
                                             format=fmt, errors='coerce',
                                             utc=fmt.endswith('Z'))
                              for fmt in formats])
```

Note that if you have a `Z` in the format, you need `utc=True`.

Example:

```
                          Date                       date_parsed
0                   01/01/2023               2023-01-01 00:00:00
1  2023-01-01T12:00:00.123456Z  2023-01-01 12:00:00.123456+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can rely on `infer_datetime_format` parameter:

> ***infer_datetime_format: bool***, *default False*
>
> If `True` and no format is given, attempt to infer the format of the datetime strings based on the first non-NaN element, and if it can
> be inferred, switch to a faster method of parsing them. In some cases
> this can increase the parsing speed by ~5-10x.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_parsed': ['01/01/2023', '2023-01-01T14:53:30.200Z']})
pd.to_datetime(df['date_parsed'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

---

```
0                 2023-01-01 00:00:00
1    2023-01-01 14:53:30.200000+00:00
```

Comment: the point of `infer_datetime_format` is to infer the datetime format for a whole column (series), assuming it is the same for all elements. if you want the parser to infer the format for each element in the series, simply do not provide a `format`.